# Reject an edit based on assumption that the edit may already fix OP's problem/code

Tags: discussion

What is the preferred course of action regarding approving/rejecting edits on questions, where the edit is modifying OP's original code in a slight way (for example adding quotes around strings etc)? I'm asking this because I'm seeing these kind of edits a lot lately and I'm not sure what to do with them.

On one hand OP may simply have made a typo or bad copy/paste while writing his question. But on the other hand this may well be OP's actual code and the edit may already fix the issues related to these errors.

Also when I do reject these edits, my reason often is **clearly conflicts with the authors intent**, or **causes harm** with an explanation like the following: `"This edit already fixes some of the problems with OP's code. These changes should either be confirmed by commenting, or must be posted as an answer."` Which one should be the preferred one in this case?

**EDIT**

Glorfindel marked my question as a duplicate, but I see 2 reasons why my question isn't a duplicate:

- First of all both answers given in the linked question have conflicting
  opinions as one of them says **edits should be rejected**, while the
  other one says **edits should be accepted**.
- Second of all the linked question is a feature request, while I'm
  merely trying to discuss what to do in a situation like this (which is a much needed discussion as proven by the fact that both answerers have a vastly different opinion).

Comment: @Glorfindel While it may possibly be a dupe of the linked question (not sure though), both answers given there are conflicting as the accepted answer says **edits should be rejected**, while the other answer says **edits should be accepted**.

Comment: There are numerous questions about this already, I just picked one. The general consensus is to reject **all* code edits, except those that fix the formatting. The risk of accidentally solving the problem is simply too great.  Your custom 'causes harm' reason seems to convey that message in the best possible way.